# Joining two file data based on column comparision

Tags: shell-script, join

I have two files each containing a timestamp and a count as follows

File1.txt

```
   9 2016-06-22
   3 2016-06-23
   2 2016-06-24
   1 2016-06-25
   2 2016-06-26
   2 2016-06-27
```

File2.txt

```
   3 2016-06-23
   2 2016-06-25
   5 2016-06-27
```

I would like to created an output where it uses the date column (col-3) in both the files and create an joined output which is as follows.

Expected result:

```
   9   2016-06-22
   3 3 2016-06-23
   2   2016-06-24
   1 2 2016-06-25
   2   2016-06-26
   2 5 2016-06-27
```

Using paste command is very complex and involves manual effort to get the expected output.Can someone help me with this ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you search [tag:join] you'll find plenty of similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use the `join` command:

```
join -j 2 -a 1 -e " " -o 1.1 2.1 1.2 File1.txt File2.txt
```

Not the more elegant solution, but if you want to learn shell-script this should do the job:

```
while read line1; do
    file1_number=$(echo ${line1} | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    file1_date=$(echo ${line1} | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    line2=$(grep ${file1_date} File2.txt)
    file2_number=$(echo ${line2} | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    if [[ -z "${file2_number}" ]]; then
        file2_number=" "
    fi
    echo ${file1_number} "${file2_number}" ${file1_date}
done < File1.txt
```